# Local authentication free SMTP server for GMail

Tags: smtp, proxy

There is an application that cannot use GMail SMTP with authentication.

I want to know if there is a possibility to create a local proxy SMTP server that will send mail via GMail? So I can assign this local server for applicaiton.

Comment: What OS is this?

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't help but laugh at the words unauntetificated and authentification. Thanks for brightening up my morning. No offense intended. Good luck with your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But for a real answer, you should give more information about the environment (scale, OS, limitations, etc.).

You might want to consider setting up your favourite Mail Transfer Agent (MTA) and searching the web and its documentation for the word 'relay'.

Postfix is a common choice in the unix/linux world. A 'real' MTA like this might be overkill, depending upon your actual needs. You might want to hand the message off to a simple script that can handle SMTP-Auth, any major scripting language can do this.

Asides:
1) Do you really need to send it through GMail's SMTP servers and not directly?

2) In English, the word is "Authentication".

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, I have recently published a free [SMTP Proxy](http://smtpproxy.codeplex.com).  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, you may want to try out [sSMTP](http://wiki.debian.org/sSMTP). It is a simple MTA and *sendmail* replacement that acts just like a proxy. The clients can just send mail to it and it will take care of authorisation with Gmail. However, since it does not have a daemon mode, you may need to work around this by using *xinetd* also.